# Everytime I clear the directions route in google map api the directions is clear when i console.log it but the route still appears on the map

Tags: reactjs, api, rendering

This is where I calculate the route:

```
async function navigate() {
    if (originRef.current.value === "" || destinationRef.current.value === "") {
      return {};
    }
    /* eslint-disable */
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    const results = await directionsService.route({
      origin: originRef.current.value,
      destination: destinationRef.current.value,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
    });
```

This is where I clear the route:

```
  function handleClear() {
    props.setDirectionsResponse(null);
    setDistance("");
    setDuration("");
    originRef.current.value = "";
    destinationRef.current.value = "";
  }
```

This is where I display the route:

```
      <GoogleMap
        zoom={10}
        center={center}
        mapContainerClassName="map-container"
        onLoad={(map) => setMap(map)}
      >
        {directionsResponse && (
          <DirectionsRenderer directions={directionsResponse} />
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
```

Every time I clear the map the route still appears on the map but does not show in my variables when I console.log it.

I think it has something to do with re-rendering the google map component but I haven't had any luck.